# Convert std::vector to JSON using CPPREST-SDK

Tags: c++, json, cpprest-sdk

At the moment I am working on a c++ project, writing the server side of an API using the CPPRESTSDK (a.k.a. Casablanca).
Serializing values such as int, double etc. is already implemented in the cpprestsdk library.

I wanted to ask now, if there is any way to serialize a `std::vector` to a `json::value` at the client, make a reqeust and then deserialize it at the server?
Something like:

```
    http_client client(U("http://localhost"));
    json::value jsonVector(std::vector);
    make_task_request(client, methods::POST, jsonVector)
```

Thank you for everything in advance!

Answer (score 3):

Vector serialization:

```
    std::vector<int> someVector;
    web::json::value json;

    std::vector<value> array;

    if (someVectory.size()) {
        for (auto num : someVector) {
            array.push_back(value(num));
        }

        json["yourKey"] = value::array(array);
    }
```

If you don't need to push the array into a container object, then just use `value::array(array)` which transforms the `std::vector` to an array.

To deserialize, let's say you have a known array in `array` then:

```
    std::vector<int> intVector;
    for (auto it=array.cbegin();it!=array.cend();++it) {
        intVector.push_back(it->as_integer());
    }
```

Comment: You can also deserialze into a _std::vector<web::json::value>_ using its constructor by iterators i.e: _std::vector<web::json::value> vec(array.cbegin(), array.cend());_.